# Call stack error on button click - Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following button that reaches out to `/api/reviews/react`:

```
"use client"

import useFetch from "@/hooks/useFetch";
import { thumbsDown, thumbsUp } from "@/public/icons";
import HTTPMethod from "http-method-enum";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function ReactOnPost({id, reactedBy, user}: {id: string, reactedBy: string[], user: string}) {

  const [data, error, loading, sendFetch] = useFetch();

  const hasReacted = (reactedBy: string[], user: string) => {
    let didReact = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < reactedBy.length; i++) {
        if (reactedBy[i] === user) {
          didReact = true;
          break;
        }
    }
    return didReact;
  }

  const reacted = hasReacted(reactedBy, user)

  if (reacted) {
    return <p>You already reacted. <button className="standard-clear-btn" style={{width: 50, height: 50, fontSize: "1rem"}}>Undo</button></p>
  }
  
    return (
        <div className="reactions">
            <Image src={thumbsUp} alt="Vote up" onClick={() => {
        sendFetch ("/api/reviews/react", HTTPMethod.PATCH, {
          id,
          like: true,
          userId: user
        })
      }}/>
            <Image src={thumbsDown} alt="Vote down" onClick={() => {
        sendFetch ("/api/reviews/react", HTTPMethod.PATCH, {
          id,
          like: false,
          userId: user
        })
      }}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The api endpoint works fine and the data is updated however upon refreshing the page (to show the data) I get an error: `Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

## `useFetch` hook:

```
import HTTPMethod from "http-method-enum";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function useFetch() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const sendFetch = async (url: string, method: HTTPMethod, body: any): Promise <any> => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const rawResponse = await fetch(url, {
                method,
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    body,
                }),
            });

            const response = await rawResponse.json();

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(response.message)
            }
            setData(response);
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.log(error)
            setError(error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return [data, loading, error, sendFetch];
}
```

## `FullReview` parent component:

```
import { Stars } from "@/app/app/components";
import { ReactOnPost } from "@/app/app/components";
import { User, Review } from "@/mongo";
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default async function FullReview({ reviewData }: { reviewData: any }) {
    const { title, stars, text, id,  createdAt, author } = reviewData;

    const signedInUser = await currentUser()

    const signedInUserStore = await User.findOne ({userId: signedInUser?.id})

    const user = await User.findOne({_id: author})

    const review = await Review.findOne ({author})

    return (
        <div className="full-review">
            <Stars count={stars}/>
            <article>
                <b>{title}:</b>
                <p>{text}</p>
            </article>
            <hr />
            <div className="actions">
            <ReactOnPost id={id} reactedBy={review.reactedBy} user={signedInUserStore._id}/>
            <span>
                {review.likes} votes
            </span>
                <span className="date">
                    Written on {createdAt.toString()} by {user.businessName}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

What's going on here? This error only happens when I use the UI to reach the endpoint. The same call stack error doesn't exist when I use postman to reach the endpoint.